# Samsung VG-KBD1500 keyboard pairs but not connects to Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, external-keyboard

I can pair my Samsung VG-KBD1500 keyboard to Nexus7, but it doesn't connect to it.
The keyboard works well with the TV, and I have another bluetotth keyboard, that paired and works well too.

1. I disconnected the Samsung kbd from the TV, and switched the TV off
2. Paired the Samsung keyboard to Nexus 7 successfully
3. When I tried to write something, the softver kbd shows up

The other bluetooth keyboard works well if I take it on.

The same issue occurs, if I unpair the working kbd and Samsung kbd and repair only the Samsung's one.

By opinion of Samsung support, the kbd should work, but it can be paired only with one device at the a time, but it doesn't in my case.
Any advice?